# Reproduced a sound with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, audio

I've searched in Google, Youtube and within Blender's own Geometry Nodes, without success, if there was any Node to reproduce a sound.

Do you know if theres a way to do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: There is no such node in Geometry Nodes. Could be done in Python, which would create a graph as a curve, geonodes could then read this curve and work on it further.

Comment: Not Blender, but a wonderful (node-based) alternative for creating audio: https://puredata.info/ ...and I'm pretty sure it can also be bridged to Blender ...somehow.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.
It's a shame it can't be done. I hope that in a new version of Blender it can be done. I think it would save a lot of time.

Comment: Possibly in a distant future, and even then not without add-ons. Generating audio is not the core task of 3D software.

Comment: It is logical what you say, it does not allow that in some cases it could be very practical.

Comment: You may want to explore Animation Nodes which supports midi tracks